# Sql Server 2012 selecting page returns wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate

Which column is choose for ordering when the only order column is the same ?

My table is like follows. The only order column is "type". 
So the sql query sentence for selecting top 5 is :

```
select top 5 from table order by type asc;
```

The sql query sentence for selecting top 10 is :

```
select top 10 from table order by type asc;
```

The top 5 of the second query result is not equal to the first top 5 query result.
Why ?
What's the second order column when type is the same for some rows ?

```
id    | type  |  name       |  content    | description
======================================================================
0       1        new1          xxxx         xxxx
======================================================================
1       1        new2          xxxx         xxxx
======================================================================
2       2        new3          xxxx         xxxx
======================================================================
3       2        new4          xxxx         xxxx
======================================================================
4       2        new5          xxxx         xxxx
======================================================================
5       3        new6          xxxx         xxxx
======================================================================
6       3        newa          xxxx         xxxx
======================================================================
7       3       newb           xxxx         xxxx
======================================================================
```

Comment: >>>The only order column is "type"<<< Why don't you use id column instead? Your type column is not unique, and id column it is

Comment: No other column is choosen and the result is unpredictable. It depends on execution plan and other things sql-server is free to choose beeing only constraint by the query.

Comment: @sepupic The table listed above is just for example.  The code was written by others, not me. I have just found the bug.

Comment: If you order the resultset by NON UNIQUE column, the result is not deterministic. It means that at the next execution it may be different even if the data was not change at all. You should order by unique column. That's all

Comment: @Serg In my situation the number of rows in a page is 20. There are 2 pages.  I found that "select top 40" always return the same result, either "select top 20". But the top 20 of them are different.

Comment: There is not any second or invisible order. If row's order is same, SQL list first available row, probably on the same page.

Comment: Under circumstances, those 20 rows brought by  "select top 20" may vary as well. No any   guaranties they will be the same forever if any other rows satisfying the query exist.

Comment: you either use a unique column (or any combination of column that guarantee uniqueness between rows) for ordering or you deal with non deterministic behaviour

Comment: @all Thanks all. I have used a combination of column that guarantee uniqueness between rows.